# iis7.5 rewrite 500.52 for sub virtual app

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, subapplication

I've just migrated from IIS6 svr2003 to IIS7.5 server 2008r2 and installed the url rewrite.  That all works great.  The website in question is large and running under .net 2 integrated pipeline.   Can't redo in .net 4 at this time.  I'm brand new to this and a bit out of my depth here.  I'd really like to use the rewrite functionality, but I need the sub-app to work also.  Any help would be appreciated.

But, a sub virtual app from an outside vendor has a problem with the rewrite section of the webconfig.  I comment it out and the sub virtual works great.  I've looked on the web and tried a few things:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

or

```
<location path="." allowOverride="true" />
```

wrapped around the rewrite module give me:  The system.web element has invalid child element location.

I tried 
     
right under the system.web in the sub virtual app's webconfig but even with the rewrite commented out - this gives an error.
I could try the remove, but wondered if someone could give me some insight on this problem.

Here's the basic rewrite:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^sethsBrochure.pdf$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="path/path/doc.pdf" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^sethsBrochure$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="path/path/doc.pdf" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
      <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^(.*)path/path/doc\.pdf$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}/ path/path/doc" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is, as you guessed, to use `clear` or `remove` in the sub application.  For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <!-- Insert rules for this application (if any) **below** the "clear" -->
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, as you found online, you can also do this using a `location` block.  The problem with what you tried is that the location block needs to be *outside* the `system.webServer` block, not inside it.

You write that you tried:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
            <rewrite>
            ...
            </rewrite>
        </location>
    <system.webServer>
<configuration>
```

Instead, you need to do this:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
            ...
            </rewrite>
        <system.webServer>
    </location>
<configuration>
```